# Can I use Firebase remote config for updating strings.xml of Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Well known that **Firebase Remote Config is a cloud service that lets you change the behavior and appearance of your app without requiring users to download an app update.**

I was wondering that can I use `Firebase Remote Config` for updating `strings.xml`?

Sometime I need to update file `strings.xml` (for example: correct the translation of locale languages). And to do this I have to update my app.

It's great if we can store the `strings` in server like `Firebase`.

Comment: `strings.xml` cannot be changed at runtime.

Comment: @AtifFarrukh Thanks.

Comment: @TOP Although you can not update the strings.xml dynamically. There's an easy solution to this. Check my answer below.

Comment: You can check this firebase solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/69600481/5142776

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot do it through Firebase, just need to update apk.

Comment: So sad to know that

Answer (score 3):

Dynamically updating strings.xml is not possible but there's a solution to this. I ran into the same problem when I wanted to do A/B testing with Firebase Remote Config. So I created [FString](https://github.com/ravindrabarthwal/FString/) library for android and it provides a smart solution. It currently powers [Mouve Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.mouve.androidbase1) on production.

### Installation

- In your project's module **build.gradle** add this dependency

```
implementation 'com.ravindrabarthwal.fstring:fstring:1.0.0'
```

- In your Android **Application** class add the following code

```
import com.example.myapp.R.string as RString // Import your string 

class MyApp: Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FString.init(RString::class.java) // Initializes the FString
    }

}
```

### Usage

**To access the strings**

```
  // This is how you get strings without FString
  context.getString(R.string.my_app_name) // This is how you normally do

  // To get the string using FString use
  FString.getString(context, R.string.my_app_name)

  // If you prefer extension function use
  context.getFString(R.string.my_app_name) // This is how FString works ;)
```

**To update the FString values**

```
  /*
   * Assume this JSON is coming from server. The JSON string 
   * must be parseable to a JSON object with key and value pairs
   */
  var jsonFromServer = """
      {
        "my_app_name": "MyApp v2.0",
        "some_other_string": "this is so cool",
      }
  """.trimIndent()

  // This will update the SharedPreference using keys from
  // above JSON and corresponding value. The SharedPreference will
  // not save any key that is not is strings.xml
  FString.update(context, jsonFromServer)
```

Check the library documentation for more info. If you find the answer helpful upvote this and mark it as the answer.