# How to remote update translation string.xml on Android without upload new APK?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Sometimes we just want to change some strings. However, we have to recompile and resign app and upload to Play Store. User also have to download and update too.

I think Firebase remote config is an interesting solution. But it seem that remote-config cannot update string.xml it self.

Any solution?

Comment: you can't update contents of APK file without re-installing it. So you won't be able to update `strings.xml`. Instead you can store string resources in some other file, which will be stored in the app's private storage, and downloaded/replaced on update.

Comment: @UmAnusorn Although you can't update the strings.xml directly. If you want a very easy solution then I have answered a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60133893/4057271

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no way to update your string.xml file but you can achieve this functionality via your api requests. So this way your every strings will be api driven and you can change whenever you want to.
There is one framework named [proteus](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/proteus). So with the help of this you can generate your complete layout dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer stated there is not official way to do that ,

But since you wanted a firebase solution here is a universal library that does just that [Telereso](https://telereso.io) , it also controls images .

add to build.gradle

```
// At your root build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // add JitPack repository
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } 
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

// At your app build.gradle
implementation("io.telereso:telereso:1.0.1-alpha")
```

Init

```kotlin
class MyApplication : Application() {
   override fun onCreate() {
      super.onCreate()
      Telereso.init(this)
   }
}
```

It support globally changing strings out of the box by adding this to styles

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/style_color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/style_color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/style_color_accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/fab_color_pressed</item>
    <item name="viewInflaterClass">io.telereso.android.RemoteViewInflater</item>
</style>
```

Or scoped changes like so

```kotlin
var text = Telereso.getRemoteString(R.strings.title) // if remote not found, R.string.tile will be used
```